# linear regression with a two level factor classification variable

Tags: r, model, linear-regression

I'm trying to do a linear regression with a two level factor classification variable:

```
train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                               number = 5, repeats = 3)
 # Train the model
 model <- train(Classification ~., data = ds, method = "lm",
                trControl = train.control)
```

> Error: wrong model type for classification

Why do I have this error? I tried yesterday doing the same thing and I didn't have any error.

Comment: If yesterday it worked see if you aren't reading de data differently. Check data types. It's hard to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: It was the same dataset yesterday

Comment: What's `str(ds)` like? It looks like a problem with the type of the response, check if `"Classification"` is a `factor`, `integer` or `numeric`.

Comment: Your Classification is factor variable. You should change method to "glm" or convert classification to numeric vector, maybe 0 and 1 then for result select closest fit, if you want to force lm.

Comment: with "glm", works now, thanks

Comment: If you have factor variable where you cannot logically assume  any order whatsoever, then you should probably use "glm" or any other classification method.